# Registration form not echoing

Tags: php, if-statement

I am very new to PHP and I cannot get this if statement to echo when you click submit. My editor isn't showing any errors with the code and it seems to work fine, except for it not echoing the errors.

```
<html>
<LINK rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' type='text/css'>

<?php
$submit = $_POST['submit'];
$username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
$password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
$repeatpassword = md5(strip_tags($_POST['repeatpassword']));

$date = date('Y-m-d');
echo $date;
if ($sumbit)
{
    if ($username&&$password&&$repeatpassword)
    {
        $password = md5($password);
        $repeatpassword = md5($repeatpassword);

        if ($password==$repeatpassword) 
        {
            if(strlen($username)>25)
            {
                echo 'Length of username must be less than 25 charcters';
            }
            else 
            {
                if (strlen($password)>25||strlen($password)<6)
                {
                    echo 'Your password must be 6 to 25 characters long';
                }
                else 
                {
                    echo 'Success!';
                }
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            echo 'Passwords do not match';
        }

    }
    else
        echo 'Fill in all the fields';
}
?>

<form action='register.php' method='POST'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Username</td><br />
        </tr>  
        <tr>  
            <td><input type='text' name='username'></td><br />
        </tr> 
        <tr>
            <td>Password</td><br />
        </tr>
        <tr>    
            <td><input type='password' name='password'></td><br />
        </tr>    
        <tr>    
            <td>Repeat Password</td><br />
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type='password' name='repeatpassword'></td><br />
        </tr>
    </table>
        <p>
            <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Register'>
</form>

</html>
```

Comment: After submitting what are you seeing? is it showing anything at all?

Comment: http://www.php.net/isset

Comment: sumbit should be submit

Comment: `sumbit` to `submit` ... typo error? should be closed the question?

Comment: there is a md5 of repeatpassword being done twice and md5 of password being done once. so the if condition fails
        if ($password==$repeatpassword)

Answer (score 3):

There is a typo

its

```
if ($sumbit)
```

should be

```
if ($submit)
```

Comment: Good eyes. I didnt see that one.

Comment: hehe because I always do these kind of typo daily :D

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought it would be something stupid like that. I am using to working with Java an it will scream at you for things like this.

Comment: If you have something like error_reporting(E_ALL); these error will never go unnoticed

Answer (score 1):

Add this at the beginning of your code:

```
ini_set("display_errors", true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

You have to enable error reporting, its turned off by default afaik. Anyways:

```
if ($sumbit)
```

I suppose you want to check if its set. The function in php for that is called `isset()`, so your code would be:

```
if(isset($submit)) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, it may help you.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $submit = $_POST['submit'];
    $username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);

    $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
    $repeatpassword = md5(strip_tags($_POST['repeatpassword']));

    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    echo $date;
    if ((isset($username))&&(isset($password))&&(isset($repeatpassword)))
    {
        $password = md5($password);
        $repeatpassword = md5($repeatpassword);

        if ($password==$repeatpassword) 
        {
            if(strlen($username)>25)
            {
                echo 'Length of username must be less than 25 charcters';
            }
            else 
            {
                if (strlen($password)>25||strlen($password)<6)
                {
                    echo 'Your password must be 6 to 25 characters long';
                }
                else 
                {
                    echo 'Success!';
                }
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            echo 'Passwords do not match';
        }


    }
    else
        echo 'Fill in all the fields';

}
```

AND For Form use :

```
<form action='' method='POST'>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Register'>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['repeatpassword']))
  {
    $username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);

    $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
    $repeatpassword = md5(strip_tags($_POST['repeatpassword']));
```

instead of

```
if ($sumbit)
{
   if ($username&&$password&&$repeatpassword)
   {
```

Answer (score 0):

your are using sumbit and use **submit**

```
if ( !empty($submit) ){


{
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a md5 of repeatpassword being done twice and md5 of password being done once. so the if condition fails

```
if ($password==$repeatpassword)
```

Before if submit condition

```
$password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
$repeatpassword = md5(strip_tags($_POST['repeatpassword']));
```

Inside if submit condition

```
$password = md5($password);
$repeatpassword = md5($repeatpassword);
```